# Direct the command to a newly opened separate command prompt using bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I have a command prompt shortcut that run a bat file when it's launched. Once it is launched I will issue another command,say my_command, which is added as doskey macro in `login.bat`

The flow is somewhat like this.

I have a cmd shortcut with target set as:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "D:\\login.bat"
```

where `login.bat` sets the environment.

Once the cmd prompt is active I should issue another command, say `my_command` (which should be run in the currently open cmd prompt)

Inside `login.bat` I have the following lines

```
...
doskey my_command=another_login.bat DEBUG 32
```

I was trying to write a bat file to do the whole thing.

I am not supposed to change `login.bat`

What I tried is :

```
start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "D:\\login.bat"
my_command
```

The command `my_command` gets run on the bat file's command prompt.

How do I make the command `my_commnad` run on the newly opened command prompt and not in the bat file's cmd prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "D:\\login.bat & devenv"
```

Answering your edit: bad news.

> You cannot run a Doskey macro from a batch file.

Reference: http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html

Can you just directly run the command you are setting up with doskey?

```
start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "D:\\login.bat & another_login.bat DEBUG 32"
```

Comment: It says devenv is not recognized as a command. But when I just try till login.bat and enter the command devenv to the prompt it works

Comment: OK. I assume login.bat sets your PATH variable. Perhaps cmd.exe looks for devenv before login.bat is executed. You could try specifying the entire path to devenv - I think everything else that login.bat does would still be applied.

Comment: I have edited my question a bit. I am supposed to run a doskey that was enetered in login.bat. I am new to writing bat file. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to devenv inside the batch file, and that path will depend on your version of Visual Studio.

Try replacing `devenv` with one of these:

VS 2013:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

VS 2012:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

VS 2010:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

### Edit in response to your comment

The `doskey.exe` executable is located in `C:\Windows\System32\doskey.exe`. Referencing it by full path should work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't completely honest in my question. Actually I didn't wanted to say the actual command that was entered. It is not devenv. It is a doskey that was added inside login.bat. After running login.bat. I am calling the doskey macro. I will rephrase my question

Comment: See my edit... Doskey.exe is an executable file as well, which you can reference by the full path too.

Comment: I think what @sajas is trying to say is he has defined a DOSKEY macro within the login.bat file and is trying to access it from the shortcut that is calling the bat file.

Comment: The main question that I have is how to run whatever command that follows (her it's my_command) in the newly opened cmd prompt, not the default cmd prompt opened by the bat file.

Comment: Thanks guys, Blorgbeards answer worked for me. Thanks for the help